# Check the type of rootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have many navigation controllers and one tab bar controller in my app. Now i want to check if currently i am on navigation view or tab bar view. How can i check for my current view class.

```
NSString *className=self.window.rootViewController.description;
NSLog(@"class name is %@ ",className);
```

When I am on navigation controller view the output is :

```
class name is <UINavigationController: 0x1cd78780>
```

And when i am on tab bar controller, It prints

```
class name is <UITabBarController: 0x1cdbd8d0>
```

How can i recognize them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the navigation controllers embedded in the Tab Bar controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
Class rootClass = [self.window.rootViewController class];

if (rootClass == [UINavigationController class]) {

} else if (rootClass == [UITabBarController class]) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy. You already spotted if its UINavigationController now all you need is to get the top view controller from your navigation controller

```
NSString *className = navigationController.topViewController.description;
NSLog(@"class name is %@ ",className);
```